# How to fetch the details of Service Bus Queue using shared access policy (Without Manage Option) connection string?

Tags: .net, azure, connection-string, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have used `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` v5 package to access service bus queue details by specifying the SAP connection string and queue name. When the SAP has `Send, Listen` access but not the `Manage` Claim option, If I try to check whether the queue exits or not in the service bus it throws the below exception

Exception: `AzureServiceBusQueue: Exception raised while checking for the availability of the configured queue: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Manage,EntityRead claims required for this operation.`

Code I have used:

```
var servicebusConnectionString = new ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
                {
                    TransportType = TransportType.Amqp
                };
NamespaceManager namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(servicebusConnectionString.ToString());
if (namespaceManager.QueueExists(path))
    return true;
```

Where as If I try the same with SAP connection string that have the access to `Manage`, I could get the queue details.

Here I am just trying to access/read the details of the queue not going to manage the entity but still, Why I need the Manage operation access?. Is there any solution to overcome this?

Note: In Service Bus Explorer also couldn't get the queue/topic details if its key doesn't have the Manage option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage permission is required to access metadata and perform entity operations.